# jaxws complex type package

Tags: java, wcf, jax-ws, jax-ws-customization

Say I have a WCF service consumed by jaxws soap generated client using wsimport.
Service SEI looks like

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "DoSomething", action = "http://mydomain.com/PersonService/Dosomething")
@WebResult(name = "DoSomethingResult", targetNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "DoSomething", targetNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/", className = "webservice.jaxws.DoSomething")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "DoSomethingResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/", className = "webservice.jaxws.DoSomething")
public Person doSomething(
    @WebParam(name = "person", targetNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/")
    Person person);
```

that takes a complex type Person and return same type Person and generated DoSomething looks like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "person"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "DoSomething")
public class DoSomething {

@XmlElement(nillable = true)
protected Person person;
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
public void setPerson(Person value) {
    this.person = value;
}
```

everything works fine if Person is same package as DoSomething, as soon as I move Person somewhere else, WCF service cannot get anything out of Person object( fields are either null or 0) , the return value from WCF cannot be deserilized correctly by JAXWS, although there were no exception.

I noticed if they are in the same package, then setPerson will be called but not if they are in different packages.

I am wondering is it possible to put the complex type Person in a different package as DoSomething.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out need the magical package-info.java file within Person's package

Comment: Defined here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html